# Self-Update a Spring-Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, auto-update

What i am trying to do is writing a self-updating Spring Boot 2.2.5 application

I wrote a little spring-boot-starter-web application with a RESTController to control the update process (i know the REST-Paths are not properly set e.g. /update/update...)

The process should look like the following:

1. Start the Spring-Boot application with self delivered AdoptOpenJDK from the application-libraries
2. Check if update is available on Server (http://localhost:8080/update/check)
3. Download the update to a local directory and unzip all files into a temporary "update-directory. (http://localhost:8080/update/download)
4. Shutdown Spring-Boot application including the JVM (http://localhost:8080/update/update)
5. Modify application folders (replace libraries and other files)
6. Start the application the same way it was started in point 1 (With self delivered AdoptOpenJDK and params)

For now i tried accomplishing this task by using the following tutorial:

> https://dzone.com/articles/programmatically-restart-java

With this example i can restart my application just fine. But i have to care for the OS specific Shell/Commands to work properly. e.g. i can't get it running on Windows together with a new CMD-Window. Only if the application is started in background i dont get any errors, or at least the application is starting and responding.

I had a look at the Spring Boot Actuator stuff aswell, but this is mostly reloading the context, but i need to swap the ressources used by the JVM currently running..

So what i want to ask: 
Is there a way to restart my Spring-Boot-Application including parameters, updating all the files from the application and restarting the JVM?

My current code is the following:

SelfupdateApplication (Spring-Boot-Start-Class)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SelfupdateApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SelfupdateApplication.class, args);
    }

    public static void update() {
        try {
            SelfupdateApplication.restartApplication(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sun property pointing the main class and its arguments. Might not be defined
     * on non Hotspot VM implementations.
     */
    public static final String SUN_JAVA_COMMAND = "sun.java.command";

    /**
     * Restart the current Java application
     * 
     * @param runBeforeRestart some custom code to be run before restarting
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void restartApplication(Runnable runBeforeRestart) throws IOException {
        try {
            // java binary
            String java = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java";
            System.out.println("Java-Home: " + java);
            // vm arguments
            List<String> vmArguments = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
            StringBuffer vmArgsOneLine = new StringBuffer();
            for (String arg : vmArguments) {
                // if it's the agent argument : we ignore it otherwise the
                // address of the old application and the new one will be in conflict
                if (!arg.contains("-agentlib")) {
                    vmArgsOneLine.append(arg);
                    vmArgsOneLine.append(" ");
                }
            }
            // init the command to execute, add the vm args
            final StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer("\"" + java + "\" " + vmArgsOneLine);

            // program main and program arguments
            String[] mainCommand = System.getProperty(SUN_JAVA_COMMAND).split(" ");
            // program main is a jar
            if (mainCommand[0].endsWith(".jar")) {
                // if it's a jar, add -jar mainJar
                cmd.append("-jar " + new File(mainCommand[0]).getPath());
            } else {
                // else it's a .class, add the classpath and mainClass
                cmd.append("-cp \"" + System.getProperty("java.class.path") + "\" " + mainCommand[0]);
            }
            // finally add program arguments
            for (int i = 1; i < mainCommand.length; i++) {
                cmd.append(" ");
                cmd.append(mainCommand[i]);
            }
            // execute the command in a shutdown hook, to be sure that all the
            // resources have been disposed before restarting the application
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            // execute some custom code before restarting
            if (runBeforeRestart != null) {
                runBeforeRestart.run();
            }
            // exit
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // something went wrong
            throw new IOException("Error while trying to restart the application", e);
        }
    }
}
```

RestController to call the single steps

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/update")
public class UpdateController {

    @GetMapping("/download")
    public boolean download() {
        File currentDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File destDir = new File(currentDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "update_lib");
        File downloadDir = new File("C:/temp/selfupdate/someServer/update");

        try {
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(downloadDir, destDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @GetMapping("/check")
    public void check() {
        // not relevant for now
        SomeHelper.checkForUpdate();
    }

    @GetMapping("/update")
    public void update() {
        SelfupdateApplication.update();
    }

    @GetMapping("/restart")
    public void restart() {
        try {
            SelfupdateApplication.restartApplication(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/alive")
    public String alive() {
        return "Yes i am still here ;-)";
    }

    @GetMapping("/shutdown")
    public String shutdown() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
        thread.start();
        return "System shutdown initiated";
    }

    @GetMapping("/version")
    public String version() {
        return "0.0.1";
    }

}
```

Thanks for reading and i appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: You may check https://github.com/update4j/update4j and https://github.com/update4j/demo-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

For the ones that want to understand the process.

This code runs a spring boot application jar from another application jar using reflection to be platform independently.

**demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** it's a simple spring boot app that I'm not including here to do not make this post too long.

The main method calls other 3 methods

- checkForUpdate - here you must include your own logic to check for update
- updateJar - this method download your application jar file from a remote server
- runjar - This one uses reflection to execute your application

It's necessary two apps, one for update the another one to don't bock the file that you want to overwrite.

```
public class Main {

    private static final String remoteJarFile = "https://www.example.org/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar";

    private static final File jarFile = new File("/home/example/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();

        if (main.checkForUpdate())
            main.updateJar();

        main.runJar();
    }

    private void runJar() throws Exception {
        URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(
                new URL[] {jarFile.toURI().toURL()},
                this.getClass().getClassLoader());

        Class mainClass = Class.forName("org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher", true, classLoader);

        Method method = mainClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);

        method.invoke(null, (Object) new String[0]);
    }

    public boolean checkForUpdate() {
        return true;
    }

    public void updateJar() throws Exception {
        BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(jarFile));

        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(remoteJarFile).openStream());

        try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0)
                outputStream.write(inputStream.read());
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```